# Shrinking a table by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, fixed-header-tables

I have a div which contains.

A table with fixed header poperty.I have achieved it by writing 2 divs first div contains a table that defines only headers and next div contains a table that has all the data.Now to keep it aligned I gave them a fixed width.

Table with fixed header is working fine.

But now here is the problem, I have to shrink and expand the table by a button click event.
Check if my following code helps. If there is another method of achieving this please suggest.

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="abc">

<div id="main-div">
   <div id="header">
     <table class="gradienttable">
       <thead>
         <tr>
             <th style="width:80px;">col 1</th>
             <th style="width:80px;">col 2</th>
             <th style="width:7px;"></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div id="data" style="overflow:auto;height:50px;width:200px;">
       <table class="gradienttable" >
         <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td style="width:80px;">data r1c1</td>
              <td style="width:80px;">data r1c2</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td style="width:80px;">data r2c1</td>
              <td style="width:80px;">data r2c2</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td style="width:80px;">data r3c1</td>
              <td style="width:80px;">data r3c2</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above table is dummy as i have a whole bunch of cols.But i have basically done it the same way.Only the height width would change.

My script is which is not working:

```
$(this).ready(function() {
  $('#abc').click(function() {
     $('div#main-div').animate({width:"100px"});
   });
});
```

Please do help me in trouble here with this.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: can you put your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work in jsfiddle. The problem is your styling.

The div with id main-div is not set to hide overflow or to show scroll bars (by default it'll just show the content that overflows the area).

Try setting style="overflow: auto" on main-div and then running your code.

```
<div id="main-div" style="overflow:auto">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slideToggle` on the `main-div` container:

```
$('input#abc').on('click', function() {
    $('div#main-div').stop().slideToggle();
})
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qUzCm/).

Comment: The thing is i want to shrink the table not hide it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for that

```
$(function(){
    $("#abc").click(function(){
     $('#main').slideToggle('slow');
});
})
```

put the visibility of div with id main as hidden in css

Comment: The thing is i want to shrink the table not hide it.